# Change background colour onClick()

Tags: android, xml, user-interface, onclick

I have a ImageView and a tag_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">

    <solid android:color="#272822">

    </solid>

    <stroke android:color="#686868" android:width="1dp">

    </stroke>

    <corners android:radius="8dp"/>
</shape>
```

What changes should i make so to :
change the background colour of the background when the imageview is clicked. i have used this tag_layout as :

```
<ImageView
            android:background="@drawable/tag_layout"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="37dp"
            android:src="@drawable/zoomin"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            />
```

How do i assign on click colours in a xml file ?

Comment: do you want to permanently change the colour of your view, or just as long as it's pressed?

Comment: as long as its pressed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be enough

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item android:state_pressed="true">
       <shape android:shape="rectangle">
           <solid android:color="#yourcoloronpressed"/>
           <stroke android:color="#686868" android:width="1dp"/>
           <corners android:radius="8dp"/>
       </shape>
   </item>
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#272822"/>
            <stroke android:color="#686868" android:width="1dp"/>
            <corners android:radius="8dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Replace the `yourcoloronpressed` by your color.

You can also change the other atributes like `stroke` and `corners` on pressed, of course.

Comment: Worked! i did almost the same thing but didn't change clickable and focus able to true so it was not working. anyways thanks alot

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help